# How to get emacs tempo mode working with abbrevs for C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, emacs

I've been experimenting with emacs tempo mode and it seems likely to save me lots of typing (always a good thing), but I haven't gotten it to work exactly the way I want it.  On the wiki, there is an example for elisp similar to what I want to do which works as expected.  Here is the complete .emacs that I tested it on:

```
(require 'tempo)
(setq tempo-interactive t)
(tempo-define-template "lambda"
                 '(> "(lambda (" p ")" n> r> ")">)
                 nil
                 "Insert a template for an anonymous procedure")
(define-abbrev lisp-mode-abbrev-table "lambda" "" 'tempo-template-lambda)
```

This allows me to type "lambda" followed by a space and have it automatically insert

```
(lambda ( )
  )
```

In my buffer with the point on the first closing parenthesis.

However, replacing the last two sexp's with the following code (stolen from Joachim Baumann via Sebastien Varrette and modified by me):

```
(tempo-define-template "c-include"
         '("#include <" r ".h>" > n)
         nil
         "Insert a #include <> statement")
(define-abbrev c-mode-abbrev-table "c-include" "" 'tempo-template-lambda)
```

Will not cause the template to be inserted after typing "c-include" followed by a space.  This is on emacs 22.2.1 running under Ubuntu 9.04.  Does anybody have any idea why this might be the case before I go digging deeper into the tempo code and/or (god forbid) the C-mode code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last argument to your `define-abbrev` should be `'tempo-template-c-include` .  Also, I'm not sure you can have a dash in there, i.e. it might have to be `cinclude` instead of `c-include`:

```
(define-abbrev c-mode-abbrev-table "cinclude" "" 'tempo-template-c-include)
```

Comment: Spot on.  The thing that was really tripping me up was the inability to include dash characters in the abbreviation.  The problem with 'tempo-template-lambda was a cut/paste error that crept in while I was experimenting with this.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `tempo` is [`yasnippet`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Yasnippet), which I found to be easier to set up interesting expansions.